Couldn't install Testlink

Fatal error: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces
is no longer supported in
D:\xampp\htdocs\testlink\third_party\kint\inc\kintParser.class.php on
line 463

I was trying to install testlink via localhost/testlink and found this error

Probably the version of this "testlink" library is not compatible with your PHP version (because the error message is telling you that part of the code has syntax which is no longer valid in newer PHP versions. No doubt there will be others which will appear, even if you fix this one yourself). Check if there's a newer version of testlink available. Or you may need to downgrade your PHP version to match what testlink is compatible with (but if it's not compatible with any currently supported PHP version that the rest of your PHP code can also work with, consider finding a different library).

P.S: https://github.com/TestLinkOpenSourceTRMS/testlink-code/tree/testlink_1_9_20_fixed/?tab=readme-ov-file#3-system-requirements---server . The notes say the next version of testLink will require PHP 7.3. But PHP 7.3 isn't even a supported version anymore. So this software is pretty out of date. The error message you're seeing was introduced in PHP 7.4! It certainly seems unlikely they would have tested it on PHP 8 yet. Only 8.2 or above is currently supported - see https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php. So I really wouldn't recommend using this "testlink" software at all.

It worked when I downgraded my Xampp to 5.6.24! Thanks :)

OK. But running on unsupported platforms is a really bad idea for security and so on

I don't recommend using Testlink but it's probably the only free tool for manual tests

I've got mine working  . . .  Go to the line indicated in the log and find the
function that has a parameter inside curly braces.  Change them to square braces.  That worked for me.  I had to do this a few times, blank screens keep coming as I do more, but that seems to be the only problem.
